# How to execute an assembly with mandatory parameters using Application Domain?

Tags: c#

I want to execute an external assembly with mandatory arguments using Application Domain (not Process).

```
        System.AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test");

        // i want to pass a mandatory arguments here.
        ad.ExecuteAssembly("something.exe");

        System.AppDomain.Unload(ad);
```

I have searched on the internet examples for that, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tyctew7.aspx) (**note** that this is obsoleted in 4.0)

```
string[] args = {"foo","bar"};
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly("something.exe", null, args);
```

or in 4.0 [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413594.aspx)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly("something.exe", args);
```